# Grunt SASS Invalid property name appearance

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, autoprefixer

When using the following SASS code

```
.select select
    -webkit-appearance: none
       -moz-appearance: none
            appearance: none
```

I'm getting a "Invalid property name" when compiling via Grunt. The problem seems to be the line with "-moz-appearance: none".

I'm using Autoprefixer, but it doesn't support the appearance property (https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#why-doesnt-autoprefixer-support-appearance).

What's the best way to let the line pass when compiling?

Comment: thanks to [web kit documentation](https://code.google.com/p/webkit-mirror/source/browse/Source/WebCore/css/CSSValueKeywords.in?spec=svnf1aea559dcd025a8946aa7da6e4e8306f5c1b604&r=63c7d1af44430b314233fea342c3ddb2a052e365) the value 'none' does not exist for appearance . You should try with a correct value.

Comment: Sass doesn't complain about invalid property names.

Comment: Ditch that formating, sass doesn't like it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty lame, but it had to do with the indenting. Had to be:

```
.select select
    -webkit-appearance: none
    -moz-appearance: none
    appearance: none
```